# span:contains() finds to many numbers

Tags: jquery, selector, contain

This code:

```
if( $('span:contains("'+user_choice+'")').length == 0 )
```

uses the [contain](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to find the `<span>`, which contains the user input. The user input `user_choice` is a number, like `1` or `23` or `31` etc.

But the code fails to find the specific `<span>`, since e.g. the user input `user_choice = 1` will find both `1` and `21` and `31` and all numbers that *contain* `1`. I need only to find the specific `<span>` that is *exactly* `1`.

Is the `contain` selector wrong for this purpose and how can I correct it to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `contains` selector is wrong for your purpose. As the name suggests it matches any element that contains the specified text as a substring, not only those elements where there's an exact match.

You could try using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var matchingElements = $('span').filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).text() === user_choice;
});
if(matchingElements.length === 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: All these years using jQuery and I can't believe I've never come across .filter() (despite being in since version 1.0). This is a much better solution than the one I provided!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` method.

```
var len = $('span').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text() == user_choice;
}).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
$('span').each(function(){
  if ($(this).html() == user_choice){
   return true;
  }
 });
```

Comment: it would return like<span>1</span>==1, better use text() method

Comment: from http://api.jquery.com/html/: "Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements". so html() will just return the contents and not the tag itself

Comment: yup. my bad. outerHTML will give the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try with each function ,it will compare all the tags of "span"

```
$('span').each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == "my_choosen_var"){
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: @Ravi Not sure what you're on about, the `.html()` method returns the `innerHTML`, so it would just be `1` if the `outerHTML` for the element was `<span>1</span>`.

Comment: There is, however, the problem that returning `true` from the function passed to `.each()` doesn't do anything to change the set of matched elements.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist my bad. lil confused.